# how to set JTextFields dynamically with a JSPinner?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jspinner

I want to add an array of `JTextFields` inside a panel with a `JSpinner` but I need to repaint the panel every time the spinner's value is changed.

How can I add that 'listener' to the spinner?

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and the [JavaDocs for `JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html)

You could attach a `ChangeListener` to the `JSpinner` using [`JSpinner#addChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html#addChangeListener(javax.swing.event.ChangeListener)), which provide notifications when the model is updated

Comment: sorry an accidentally clic, I´m checking the javadoc, thank you so much